# Spring Boot UserDetailsService getting all users with same username

Tags: spring

Im going trough project https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth#spring-rest-service-oauth and inside is class:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
```

and inside I override method

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    List<User> user = userRepository.findUserByLogin(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
    }
```

my question is can I get all Users with identical username?

Comment: Is not `userName`a primary key? How should be duplicated?

Comment: does has to be? Primary key can be id (integer)